# How to store and get data from .model()

Tags: python, qt, pyqt

The code below creates a single `QListView` with `.model()`.
On `itemClicked` I am trying to access `index.data()` to get its value stored earlier with `self.setData(index, QtCore.QVariant(inst))`. But instead of returning a value stored (such as `['Bison','Panther','Elephant']`,`['Duck','Hawk','Pigeon']`) it returns a name of the key (such as `'Animals'`,`'Birds'` or `'Fish'`). What should be changed in a code to make it work as intended?

[image]

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
app=QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv) 

class Model(QtCore.QAbstractListModel):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        QtCore.QAbstractListModel.__init__(self, *args)
        self.items=[]    
    def rowCount(self, parent=QtCore.QModelIndex()):
        return len(self.items)    
    def data(self, index, role=QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole):
        if index.isValid():
            if role == QtCore.Qt.ItemDataRole:
                return self.data(index)
            elif role==QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole:                
                return QtCore.QVariant(self.items[index.row()])

    def addItems(self, instDict):
        for key in instDict:
            inst=instDict.get(key)
            index=QtCore.QModelIndex()
            self.beginInsertRows(index, 0, 0)
            self.setData(index, QtCore.QVariant(inst))    
        self.items.extend(instDict)
        self.endInsertRows()

class ListView(QtGui.QListView):
    def __init__(self):
        super(ListView, self).__init__()
        self.model= Model()
        self.model.addItems({'Animals':['Bison','Panther','Elephant'],'Birds':['Duck','Hawk','Pigeon'],'Fish':['Shark','Salmon','Piranha']})
        self.setModel(self.model)
        self.clicked.connect(self.itemClicked)
        self.show()
    def itemClicked(self, index):
        print 'self.data(index).toString(): %s'%index.data().toString()
        print 'self.model.data(index).toString(): %s'%self.model.data(index).toString()

window=ListView()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

## EDITED LATER:

Here is a fully working example with nested dictionary as the data argument.

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
app=QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
elements={'Animals':{1:'Bison',2:'Panther',3:'Elephant'},'Birds':{1:'Duck',2:'Hawk',3:'Pigeon'},'Fish':{1:'Shark',2:'Salmon',3:'Piranha'}}

class Model(QtCore.QAbstractListModel):
    def __init__(self):
        QtCore.QAbstractListModel.__init__(self)
        self.items=[] 
        self.modelDict={}       

    def rowCount(self, parent=QtCore.QModelIndex()):
        return len(self.modelDict)   

    def data(self, index, role):
        if index.isValid():
            if role==QtCore.Qt.ItemDataRole:
                key=str(index.data().toString())
                returnedValue=self.modelDict.get(key)
                return QtCore.QVariant(returnedValue) 

            elif role==QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole:
                return QtCore.QVariant(self.items[index.row()]) 

    def addItems(self):
        for key in self.modelDict:
            index=QtCore.QModelIndex()
            self.beginInsertRows(index, 0, 0)
            self.items.append(key)

            inst=self.modelDict.get(key)
            self.setData(index, QtCore.QVariant(inst), QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole)            

        self.endInsertRows()        

class ListView(QtGui.QListView):
    def __init__(self):
        super(ListView, self).__init__()
        self.model= Model()
        self.model.modelDict=elements
        self.model.addItems()
        self.setModel(self.model)
        self.clicked.connect(self.itemClicked)
        self.show()

    def itemClicked(self, index):
        itemTitle=self.model.data(index, QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole).toString()
        itemData=self.model.data(index, QtCore.Qt.ItemDataRole).toPyObject()
        print 'itemTitle: "%s" itemData: %s'%(itemTitle,itemData)

window=ListView()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
app=QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv) 

class Model(QtCore.QAbstractListModel):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        QtCore.QAbstractListModel.__init__(self, *args)
        self.items=[]
        self.modelDict = None

    def rowCount(self, parent=QtCore.QModelIndex()):
        return len(self.items)   

    def data(self, index, role=QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole):
        if index.isValid():
            if role == QtCore.Qt.ItemDataRole:
                return self.data(index)
            elif role==QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole:
                return QtCore.QVariant(self.items[index.row()])

    def getData(self, data):
        return self.modelDict[str(data)]

    def addItems(self, instDict):
        for key in instDict:
            inst=instDict.get(key)
            index=QtCore.QModelIndex()
            self.beginInsertRows(index, 0, 0)
            self.setData(index, QtCore.QVariant(inst), QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole)
        self.items.extend(instDict)
        self.endInsertRows()
        self.modelDict = instDict

class ListView(QtGui.QListView):
    def __init__(self):
        super(ListView, self).__init__()
        self.model= Model()
        self.model.addItems({'Animals':['Bison','Panther','Elephant'],'Birds':['Duck','Hawk','Pigeon'],'Fish':['Shark','Salmon','Piranha']})
        self.setModel(self.model)
        self.clicked.connect(self.itemClicked)
        self.show()

    def itemClicked(self, index):
        print 'self.data(index).toString(): %s'%index.data().toString()
        print 'self.model.data(index).toString(): %s'%self.model.getData(index.data().toString())

window=ListView()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I am not sure this is right method but this works :)

Comment: Works like a charm! Thanks! Would you please clarify... when `index.data()` is calling `data()` method how does it knows which value to return: how does `data()` choose between `ItemDataRole` or `DisplayRole`? Since while calling `index.data()` we don't specify for what Role we want a returned value how does `.data()` know which to return?...